# Um int pode ser igual a null?

Tags: java, tipagem

Depois de ver uma pergunta relativa a isso, e muitos colegas de faculdade com dúvidas atreladas a isso, resolvi fazer este questionamento.

- O tipo `int` pode ser igual a `null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como bem dito na resposta do @pmargreff, `int` sob nenhuma hipótese será `null`.

Mas e se a variável do tipo `int` não for inicializada, com que valor ela fica afinal?

Depende, se a variável pertencer a classe ela é inicializada automaticamente com o valor `0`, se for uma variável de um método ela não será inicializada automaticamente, para essa condição ela **deve** ser explicitamente inicializada no código, caso contrário ele não compilará.

De forma similar ao tipo primitivo, variáveis de referência do tipo Integer da instância da classe também são inicializadas, entretanto como `null`, enquanto nos métodos enfrentam exatamente a mesma situação da variável primitiva: não são inicializadas implicitamente gerado um erro de compilação caso se tente acessar o seu valor. Exemplo:

```
public class TesteInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TesteInt().teste();
    }

    int iInstancia;
    Integer objInstancia;

    public void teste() {
        int iLocal;
        Integer objLocal;
        System.out.println(iInstancia);
        System.out.println(objInstancia);
        //System.out.println(iLocal); //erro de compilação
        //System.out.println(objLocal); //erro de compilação
    }
}
```

Saída:

> 0
>   null

Caso as linhas que indicam `erro de compilação` forem descomentadas, de fato, o código não terá condições de ser compilado.

Comment: Complementou bem, ví agora que acabei fugindo um pouco do escopo : )

Answer (score 8):

Resposta curta:

- Não, um `int` nunca terá como valor `null`

Resposta longa:

Em java quase tudo é um objeto, ou `Object`, mas nem tudo, e o que não é um objeto é um tipo primitivo (`primitive`). E apenas objetos podem ter o valor `null`.

A diferença de maneira mais resumida é que objetos contém uma referência para estados e comportamentos ou seja variáveis e métodos, respectivamente. E tipos primitivos tem apenas um valor.

São tipos primitivos:

- int
- byte
- short
- long
- float
- double
- char
- boolean

Caso precisarmos usar os tipos primitivos como objetos temos a classe `wrapper`, que *transforma* os tipos primitivos para que possam ser utilizados em situações em que os tipos primitivos não podem ser operados, apenas objetos. Um exemplo disso são as coleções (classe `Collections`) que só operam objetos.

A informação acima pode ser contraditória se você já criou e/ou manipulou algum tipo de coleção utilizando tipos primitivos. Isso ocorre por que o java tem uma funcionalidade chamada `Autoboxing and Unboxing`, que faz a conversão automática quando estamos usando tipos primitivos mas só poderíamos usar objetos. Isso é, faz a chamada da classe `wrapper` automaticamente.

Exemplo:

```
  java.util.Stack<Integer> pilha = new Stack();  
  int num = 10;  
  pilha.push(num);
```

O valor para `num` não poderá ser `null` mesmo depois da inserção na pilha, porque e que foi inserido na pilha foi um objeto equivalente (nesse caso um `Integer`) e o `num` continua sendo um `int`.

---

[Referência 1: Can an int be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java)

[Referência 2: How to check if an int is a null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747859/how-to-check-if-an-int-is-a-null)

[Referência 3: int x Integer:](http://www.guj.com.br/java/46348-int-x-integer)

[Referência 4: Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)