# Tentar criar arrays de duas dimensoes como objetos

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando criar um programa simples que me permite criar matrizes 2d (matriz) com objetos diferentes.

O meu processo de pensamento foi que eu deveria ser capaz de criar objetos com argumentos (como declarado no início da classe e referido no construtor) e que criariam automaticamente uma matriz com a dimensão `m => linhas; n => colunas`, passada como parâmetros do construtor do objeto. Então, eu tentei dar valores diretamente a cada célula da matriz.

Então, este é o código:

```
public class Matrix {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner (System.in);   
    int m;
    int n;
    int [][] arr = new int[m][n];

    Matrix(int a, int b){
        m = a;
        n = b;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Matriz m1 = new Matrix(3,2);
      //System.out.println(m1.m +" "+ m1.n); -> Mostra corretamente os valores "3" e "2"
      m1.arr[0][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[1][1] = 1;
      m1.arr[2][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[0][1] = 1;
      m1.arr[1][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[2][1] = 1;


      //Matrix m2 = new Matrix(3,2);

    }
}
```

O Netbeans não mostrou erros, mas quando tentei correr o programa, recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at pacote1.Matriz.extra(Matriz.java:32)     at
>   pacote1.Matriz.main(Matriz.java:43)
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Quando procurei esse erro aqui no stackoverflow, comecei a entender que esse erro significa que estou tentando acessar um índice que não existe na matriz, e isso deve significar que não tive sucesso na tentativa de dar valores para 'm' e 'n' como argumentos do objeto.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema no seu código é que você inicia o array antes de receber os valores pra definir sua dimensão, e isso é consequência da [ordem de inicialização de classes do java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118779/28595). Como as variáveis `m` e `n` são primitivas do tipo `int` e não são inicializadas, [o valor de inicialização padrão definido pra elas é 0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/65674/28595) e acabam por iniciar o array com dimensão 0x0. Passando a criação do array para o construtor conforme abaixo, ele só vai iniciar o array após `m` e `n` receber os valores desejados para sua dimensão.

Veja o código corrigido:

```
public class Matrix {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner (System.in);   
    int m;
    int n;
    int [][] arr;

    Matrix(int a, int b){
        m = a;
        n = b;
        arr = new int[m][n];
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Matrix m1 = new Matrix(3,2);
      //System.out.println(m1.m +" "+ m1.n); -> Mostra corretamente os valores "3" e "2"
      m1.arr[0][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[1][1] = 1;
      m1.arr[2][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[0][1] = 1;
      m1.arr[1][0] = 1;
      m1.arr[2][1] = 1;


      //Matrix m2 = new Matrix(3,2);

    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/yvhn16

Comment: Resolvido. Muito obrigado :)